# Problem with drawing magnetic moments with ListVectorPlot3D

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to visualize a 3D magnetic structure which is given by the following list of vectors:

```
daje={{{{{{0., 0., 0.5}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0., 0., 1.5}, {0, 0, 1}}}, {{{0., 
  1., 0.5}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0., 1., 1.5}, {0, 0, 1}}}}, {{{{1., 0., 
  0.5}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{1., 0., 1.5}, {0, 0, 1}}}, {{{1., 1., 
  0.5}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{1., 1., 1.5}, {0, 0, 1}}}}}, {{{{{0.5, 
  0.5, -0.5}, {0, 0, -1}}, {{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {0, 0, -1}}}, {{{0.5,
   1.5, -0.5}, {0, 0, -1}}, {{0.5, 1.5, 0.5}, {0, 
  0, -1}}}}, {{{{1.5, 0.5, -0.5}, {0, 0, -1}}, {{1.5, 0.5, 
  0.5}, {0, 0, -1}}}, {{{1.5, 1.5, -0.5}, {0, 0, -1}}, {{1.5, 1.5,
   0.5}, {0, 0, -1}}}}}}
```

I choose a selected grid of points over which to draw the vectors:

```
maglia = {{0.`, 0.`, 0.5`}, {0.5, 0.5, -0.5}, {1, 0.`, 0.5`}, {1.5, 0.5, -0.5}}
```

I use the command:

```
ListVectorPlot3D[daje, VectorPoints -> maglia, VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow", VectorScale -> {Large, 0.5, Automatic}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

but the output is wrong: in each point it shows two magnetic vectors (see picture), one up and one down. What's wrong with my procedure?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't help.

Comment: daje has the dimensions: {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3}. However, it should be {n,n,n,3} with a positive integer n.

Comment: Daniel, if I try flatten[daje,2] I get dimensions {8, 2, 2, 3} but then when I try to plot I get a blanck output.

Comment: The dimension along any axis must be at least 3.

Comment: Can you explain what the data is supposed to be? What are the triples, and how do they relate to one another? Why are they grouped the way they are?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: The arrows representing the moments must be either up or down but not both on each site.